# Rails session[:lists_page] with paginate not work only on Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On Ruby 2.2.10, Rails 4.2.10

Using Paginate gem, 3.0.6

This does not happen in development, only production, and yes, I have therubyracer set to load in production in the gem file.

For user convenience, I use a session variable to store the page of a Paginate instance, so if the screen refreshes with content in the center of a page, the Paginate list on the right remains on that same page.

It works fine on Firefox and Safari, but on Chrome, it reverts to the first page. Like the session variable is not being stored ( but yet it is when running the other browser types. Odd since the session variable is on the server and not the browser )

MYLISTS_ROWS is an environment variable set to 10

controller code:

```
  if  params[:lists_page] == nil
    #logger.info("lists_page parameter is nil ")
  else
    # set session variable of last mylists page
    session[:lists_page] = params[:lists_page]
  end

  # get ftypes for list of ftypes
  @mylists = List.my(current_user.id).ftypes.paginate(:page => session[:lists_page], :per_page => MYLISTS_ROWS)
```

Comment: I deleted cookie for the app since there were 2 session variables. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In production on AWS, in the chrome browser, there were 2 session cookies for my app. I flushed the cookies, and now it works.